# Duplicating control action

Tags: vb.net

In Vb.net I have a button on one form (call it button_abc), changes color, the text changes, has a click event, etc.  I want to have the SAME button duplicated on another form so that it can be used from 2 different places (one of the forms might not be visible).  When the text or color gets changed on one, it need to appear in both.  So if both forms are open, the buttons always appear to match exactly in appearance and action.  is there a way to "link" them together automatically?

Copying & pasting a button, simply creates a new (separate) button---not what I want.

Comment: Are you asking how to fire a button event one one form when a different button on a different form is clicked?

Comment: I would imagine that in the sense of easy .. its not possible - You'll probably have to write/rewrite every event handler that you want to link and have each handler handle events from both buttons and update the properties of both buttons accordingly - unless of course a more experienced user knows how else to do it

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to go down the path of using an adapter to allow you to update the buttons.

Something like this:

```
Public Class ButtonList
    Inherits List(Of Button)

    Public Property Color() As Color
        Get
            Return Me.Select(Function (b) b.Color).FirstOrDefault()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Color)
            For Each b In Me
                b.Color = Value
            Next
        End Set
    End Property

    ' + all other relevant properties.

End Class
```

Since it inherits from `List(Of Button)` you just add all the buttons you need to this class using `.Add(button)` and then put in all of the properties that you want to update. Now the code appears very much the same, but you now will update many buttons at once.

Comment: I stand corrected. I completely didn't think of the fact you can pass multiple buttons into the class. However in one of  the comments to my (rather crude) answer the OP mentions that both buttons need to control a set of "motors" I can only assume are not on either form... The adapter works to control the "identical" buttons, but what about the other controls? What are they? The requirement itself seems a bit convoluted to me TBH.

Comment: The requirement seems a bit convoluted to me ..this is NOT convoluted at all.  I have an app with many controls that works fine.  I now need a user form that has a FEW of the exact same controls that are on the main app. Just like if you had a stereo in your den and now wanted to add some speakers to the kitchen.  These controls must be duplicates of the others.  What happens to one happens to the other (automatically, if possible).  Push the button in the main form or the new form.  If some routine changes the color of the original button, the new button color changes automatically as well.

Comment: @Hoyt777 - What you really need for this is an MVVM-type pattern. Then you just update your model (M) which computes the view-model (VM) that then updates the view (V). Each button is the view. Each button would have its own view-model, but you'd only have one model that you update as needed. The model would have a property like `bool Active` which the view-model would translate to `Color ForeColor` which then gets bound to the button's `ForeColor` property.

Comment: @Hoyt777 It's really not up to you to decide what OTHER people find convoluted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you always want the buttons to match, it doesn't matter if one form is open/visible or not. You simply create 2 buttons, 1 on each form and make them do the same thing on both forms. So some pseudo-code may look like this:

Form 1:

```
Button.ClickEvent
  Me.Color = UglyGreen
  Form2.Button.Color = UglyGreen
End Button.ClickEvent
```

Form 2:

```
Button.ClickEvent
  Me.Color = UglyGreen
  Form1.Button.Color = UglyGreen
End Button.ClickEvent
```

It's not a very pretty solution, but it works for the specified task.

Comment: Well, the first (main) button has click & double click events that control some motors.  I want the secondary (duplicate button) to do these as well...basically an exact "remote duplicate" of the original button.  I was hoping to do this without having to link them together parameter-by--parameter in code, especially since I want to do this with several pairs of buttons.  I was hoping for a more automated way of linking them together.

Comment: There is no magic way of doing this. You can write a function that performs a set of actions and call this function from both buttons. It looks as if (if I understand the problem you are trying to solve correctly) that is as close as you will get. Also, giving one button both a click and a double click event seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: Sounds like just brute-force double up everything (which I originally began to do).  For example, I have some other routine that blinks the original button color, so I was hoping to link them together so if the first one is blinking, so would the second button.  I was just hoping there was some way to link/tie/clone the buttons to act as "one".

Comment: Even if you write it as a class and button color (for example) becomes a property of that class, if you want to use that property in 2 different buttons in your UI, you will still have to duplicate the code that grabs the property from the class and performs the appropriate action for the specific button. A certain amount of duplication is inevitable. That said, this is starting to sound like an XY Problem :D

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to make "twins", (but was hopeful) . This came about since I have a password protected form, but want to add a much smaller non-protected form with some of the same (duplicated) controls.

Comment: Ok, so maybe not an XY problem ;-) But why not simply create 1 form that disables the controls that should only be allowed after password verification and then just enable them after the password is verified?

Comment: what is an XY problem?    There are 2 screens that will need the same control.  In some cases you may have both screens open.  In other cases, only one of the screens.  So the same control should appear in both.

Answer (score 0):

This is along the lines of what I'm describing, except I'm using VB
[Duplicate WebControls at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13663/Duplicate-WebControls-at-Runtime-for-Better-Web-Us)